# Where can I find the source code for DomainModelTemplate in the latest DevForce version

Tags: devforce

Back in DevForce 2010, the source code for DomainModelTemplate (and related files) was included in the installation package:

[image: DevForce 2010 Installation Folder]

However, in the latest DevForce 2012 installation (7.2.2.0), I don't see those files:

[image: DevForce 2012 Installation Folder]

I've even looked in the extension directory but all that has is the T4 template - which just references the DomainModelTemplate class - it's not the actual source of that class.  The extension directory does have the CodeGenerator DLLs which is where the compiled class is.  But I'd like to avoid having to decompile the DLL just to look at the source code.

[image: Extension Directory]

According to the documentation for 2012 on "[Customizing the DevForce code generation template](http://drc.ideablade.com/devforce-2012/bin/view/Documentation/custom-code-generation-template)", these files should have been available in the installation package:

> The source code for DomainModelTemplate is shipped with DevForce; find
>   it in the DevForce installation directory.

I want the source because I am upgrading to DevForce 2012 and I want to see what has changed in the T4s since the version I'm upgrading from.

Is there some other place to get these files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry for the confusion. You can find the T4 templates in the Visual Studio extensions directory.

For example, for VS2012, the T4 templates is located inside one of the (unfortunately) cryptic folder names under the following directory,

[CurrentUserFolder]\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\Extensions

Comment: See my latest edit.  I already looked in the extension folder but that doesn't have the source code.  Specifically, I'm looking for the ~100kB file BaseDomainDataModelTemplate.cs.  The files in the Extension directory are just tiny T4 templates that reference the class.

Comment: Sorry for my misunderstanding. I had thought you were looking for the T4 templates.

Yes, we decided to exclude the source code when we decided to nugetize DF2012. 

In any case, you can download them [here](ftp://www.ideablade.com/DevForce2Support/DomainModelTemplateSourceCode.zip)

Comment: Great, thanks. Are there plans to distribute those files as part of future releases? Part of our process for upgrading to a new version of DevForce is to see what changes have been made to the T4s (because there are some places where we need to override the default behavior).  I'd rather not have to make a request each time to get the files.

Comment: Yes. Instead of including them in the nuget package, we will include those files in DF2012 jump start installer in future releases. You can download the installer [here](http://www.ideablade.com/download-portal/login.aspx)